# save the data from the range of 5001 bytes to 5200 bytes from a file to another file

Tags: python

I have a assignment that needs to Write a script that uses the MeSH file d2013.bin (given file from professor) as the input file, and outputs the first 500 bytes of data on the computer screen,and also save the data from the range of 5001 bytes to 5200 bytes in a file named q1a_out.txt. Save the script as (q1a.py). However, I don't know how to output the specific range of bytes.

```
input_file = open('d2013.bin',"rb")
out_file = open('q1a_out.txt',"wb")
first500 = input_file.read(500)
print(frist500)
input_file.close
output_file.close
```

Comment: You already know how to read 500 bytes. Now read 4500 more, and discard those; then read 200 more into another variable, and `write` those to the output file.

Comment: Also probably fix the spelling of `frist500`, and add the missing parentheses to the `close()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `seek` function to position the read pointer to the 5001 byte in the file and read 200 byte from there. See: [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)